# VS2010 Setup Deployment project, can't write HKLM registry key

Tags: c#, deployment, registry

In Visual Studio 2010 I have a c# windows application created and a setup deployment project.
Under configuration manager, the app is targeted at x86 but I cannot choose what the setup project targets as there is no dropdown available for this.

In the setup deployment project, I right click - view - registry and create the following . . 
Under  `HKLM/Software/Manufacturer`
I add Microsoft, then under that I add Windows, then under that I add CurrentVersion, then under that I add Run, so I end up with `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`.
Inside run I add a new string value for my app and set its value to `"[TARGETDIR]my_app.exe" /R`

This all compiles fine, when I run the installer on a target machine, it installs the Application but the registry entry does not get written.   I have tried installing my Application on windows 7 32-bit and 64-bit, neither gets the key created.  In `regedit`, the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`  exists and I can navigate to it but my entry is not there.  I can create it manually so why can't the installer do it?

All I want is to set this key on any target machine no matter what the target is - 32-bit or 64 bit, XP, or Vista or Win7/8

Comment: change `[TARGETDIR]my_app.exe" /R` to `[TARGETDIR]\my_app.exe" /R`

Comment: Makes no difference, nothing gets written.  Just a note, I notice that if I deploy my setup.exe on a 64bit maching, it writest the entry to the following key - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\OurComapnyName\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
 1. Will Windows catch this at startup and run my app?
 2. What about 32bit OS?

Comment: Iv ejust restarted my machine and my app did not auto start so the registry entry at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\OurComapnyName\Microsoft\Windows\Current‌​Version\Run is useless.  Why wont this work?  such a simple requirement and Im spending hours at it...

Comment: \OurComapnyName\ why this middle of key path? Every thing is fine but you should not add this

Comment: have a look at http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/109/

Comment: Is [Manufacturer] key is present in setup program? it shouldn't be there in this scenario

Comment: Sarvesh you were right. IN VS2010, deployment project, when I view the registry, under HKLM there is a key called [Manufacturer] that is there by default. I was creating my hierarchy of subkeys under that when I should have been creating them beside it.  
So the correct way is HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

The incorrect way is HKLM\[Manufacturer]\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

Many thanks for help

Comment: gud to know that you have moved a step forward  :)